# MongoDB Materialized View - How to incrementally update the output result?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to create a Materialized View in MongoDB and figured out most of it except for one part(and it is crucial).

Use-Case:
I have a list of records, and they are dynamic in nature (updated daily or on user's action)

eg. Let's call it `EmployeeSalary`

```
{
'month': 'jan',
'employee_id': 1,
'duration': 15, (days) 
'salary': 1000  (USD),
'client_id': 'c1'

}
```

```
{
'month': 'jan',
'employee_id': 2,
'duration': 15, (days) 
'salary': 1500  (USD),
'client_id': 'c2'
}
```

and so on ..

I want to create a materialized view on the `salary` attribute and that's straightforward. Here the result will be `2500`

But now the issue is: these records can change. For eg., if the salary of the employee with `id`: `1` changes from `1000` to `2000`, then I want the materialized view to have the updated value, i.e., from `2500` to `3500`

Basically, it should look like `OldAggregateValue - oldRecordValue + newRecordValue` => 2500 - 1000 + 2000 = 3500

Is there a way to just update this record's value instead of summing everything up again? It matters here because I have close to 25,000 such records and this is done for multiple clients. I need this operation to be as efficient as possible.

I have read the mongo's official docs but they have not mentioned this in the provided example([On-Demand Materialized View: Update/Replace Data](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#std-label-merge-mat-view-refresh)) They have just mentioned about updating/inserting in the output collection.

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever found the answer you were looking for, but I just finished a feature that uses an on-demand materialized view fed by a changestream to calculate and emit real-time status updates. My view was updated continuously and incrementing records as changes were received was the only way to do this efficiently.

I followed [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/on-demand-materialized-views-a-scalable-solution-for-graphs-analysis-or-machine-learning-w-d3816af28f1) and [this section](https://www.practical-mongodb-aggregations.com/examples/trend-analysis/incremental-analytics.html) of Mongo's Aggregation book as guides - both were really helpful in thinking through different use cases and implementations.

In summary, to process incremental operations, you need to set up a pipeline for processing subsets of data. The above examples use timestamps in a `$match` stage to limit which records are being processed. In my case, trying to use timestamps and process multiple change events from a changestream was too messy and I ended up using `_id`s to ensure I captured each event exactly once.

To change the view, I used a custom `$project` pipeline in the merge stage to dictate the `$merge` stage's behavior when a document was matched. In the end, my `$merge` stage looked something like:

```
      const mergeStage = {
        $merge: {
          into: 'demo-view',
          on: '_id',
          whenMatched: [{
            $project: {
              aggregate: "$total",
              increment: "$$new.total",
              total:{$sum: ["$total", "$$new.total"]}, // instead of replace the document, this $project pipeline increments the total when the document exists
              other_property: 1, 
              _id: 1,
            }
          }],
          whenNotMatched: "insert"
      }}
```

This dictates that documents should be incremented when they are matched, but if no match is found, the new document should be inserted. You'll need to customize for your specific purpose, but I found this to be a good template for my code.